# how to remove class from body in jquery using angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Using `jQuery`

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#pid1").removeClass("login_page");
  });
```

`HTML`

```
<body  class="login_page" id="pid1" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
```

In the main page class gets removed but **login page also remove class but  I have to keep the class in the login page.**

> loginpage.html

```
<div class="login_page">
</div>
```

**when I add remove class function it's work and I have tried to keep the login_page class in loginpage.html.**

Comment: i did not get your question, you want to remove `login_page` class for body where id='pid1' and not from others right? but that id is getting repeated in some other pages?

Comment: Your question is unclear, the code you posted is fine, what do you want to do differently?

Comment: Change the  `id` in your login page. Or write your script only in the main page.

Comment: @Esko it's simple index page remove class but I have to keep the class in the login page.

Comment: @TalkNit id not given in login page only given in the body of the index page.

Comment: Why are you mixing AngularJS and jQuery? They both use different approaches for adding and removing classes from elements.

Comment: @HTom ok, thx for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you:

In below code `.login_page_class` can be your class which is **present only in your login page.**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if($(".login_page_class").length == 0){
   $("#pid1").removeClass("login_page");
  };
});
```

*Added a condition to check if `.login_page` is present in the page and if it is then don't execute the code.*

Hope this was helpful for you.

Comment: if``$(".login_page").length == 0` is true then you will never remove class as there is no such element present

Comment: @Rushidave Sorry, I have updated the code, please check. I misplaced the class.

Comment: I updated but not working index and log in both page remove class

Comment: @Rushidave did you add only to login page.?  please add a new class only to the login page and replace `.login_page_class`  with the class you added in the login page and it will work.

Comment: @weBBer yes, only login page .   in the login page, I replaced class but not working.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle or live link so I can check!

Comment: @weBBer I tried fiddle but both HTML file so it's confusing to how to run in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution for this is below which will remove the body class on load.

`window.onload = function () { document.body.className = ""; }`

If you do have concern with other lib then you can try below solution as well.

`window.addEventListener(
    'load',
    function load()
    {
        window.removeEventListener('load', load, false);
        document.body.classList.remove('preload');
    },
    false
);`

Using addEventListener means that it won't interfere with any other event listeners that may be attached by other libs, etc.

The above code will remove the event listener once the event has fired too.

Comment: @ Rahul Dhmecha I already tried this solution but it's shown same error btw tx for the response.

Comment: @Rushidave Which angular version you are using. Try nginit and remove class at this stage will help you to add and remove the class.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue and its' work for me,

add and remove class manually 
in index controller and login controller, I remove class function in the index page and added class function in the login page.

Remove function

```
       $(document).ready(function()
         {
          $("body").removeClass("login_page");
        });
```

Add function

```
    $(document).ready(function()
      {
       $("body").addClass("login_page");
      });
```